# _form_comment_form_alter for certain node type

Tags: 7, comments, forms

When using the hook_form_comment_form_alter, how do I only target the comment form of a single content type?

Right now it is targeting all comment forms, and I need it to just target the 'Blog' content type comment forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use comment form ID for that content type: hook_form_comment_node_xxx_form_alter

which comment_node_xxx_form is comment form id for content type xxx:

```
function hook_form_comment_node_xxx_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hook_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $node = $form['#node'];
  if ($node->type == 'blog') {
    // do something
  }
  ...
}
```